# Automated meeting requests, timezones and exchange

Tags: exchange-2016

we just found a weird issue with our Microsoft Exchange setup: Whenever someone sends us an ics meeting request without timezone info (mostly from poorly written apps which don't seem to know the concept of timezones), for example with these values:

```
DTSTART:20161219T130000
DTEND:20161219T140000
```

No TZID or other timezone fields are used, and the timestamps are in local time (13:00 and 14:00 in the example). This way our Exchange Server creates a calendar entry for an hour later (14:00-15:00), I'm guessing using UTC as base and converting to the timezone of the mailbox (the regional settings of the mailbox are set correctly to "W. Europe Standard Time" for Europe/Berlin, which is UTC+1)

If the same request is sent to a different Exchange server (tested with a hosted mailbox, also in Germany), the times are correct. If the ICS content is opened on a client with Outlook installed, the times are also read correctly as the intended 13:00 till 14:00.

What option is missing on our Exchange server?